# An article by Jacob Pandian

Tags: philosophy-of-science, reference-request, philosophy-of-religion

There is an article named "The Dangerous Quest for Cooperation Between Science and Religion" by Jacob Pandian. I could not find it online.

The article is also in a book *Science and religion: Are they compatible* by Paul Kurtz.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it appears to be an article request.

Comment: @virmaior These type of questions don't appear to be prohibited; there's a "[reference-request](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/tags/reference-request/info)" tag.

Comment: I was able to find it online (not for free, as with most journal articles one would need to pay) by googling the name of the article.

Comment: @JamesKingsbery Can you access it via the link in my answer below?

Comment: @Geremia your answer satisfies me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reference is: [*The Skeptical inquirer*. 25, no. 5, (2001): 28](http://go.galegroup.com/ps/i.do?id=GALE%7CA77757765&v=2.1&u=uarizona_main&it=r&p=AONE&sw=w&asid=412362cf32fdc34ab188e190aec91b55)